# Why do I get so many files when I submit my Python Flask web app to Heroku?

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask

I'm following the Python/Flask tutorial on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

These are the steps I take:

```
heroku login
mkdir MyFlaskApp
python virtualenv.py MyFlaskApp --distribute
source MyFlaskApp/bin/activate
cd MyFlaskApp
pip install Flask
pip freeze > requirements.txt
foreman start
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
heroku create MyFlaskApp
git push heroku master
```

However, when I do the git add & commit, I get a lot of files. In the tutorial, `git push heroku master` reports `Counting objects: 10`, but I get `Counting objects: 425`.

What could be the problem?

The only difference I see is that the tutorial doesn't mention navigating to the app's folder (e.g. `cd MyFlaskApp`).

**UPDATE:** this is my folder structure in the folder `MyFlaskApp` after going through the steps above:

```
bin/
include/
lib/
Procfile
app.py
requirements.txt
.gitignore
```

**UPDATE 2:** My `.gitignore` file (as in the tutorial):

```
venv
*.pyc
```

Comment: You might appreciate this: https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually creating the virtualenv in your local directory. You'll either want to create it in the venv directory or add each of the three following items to your .gitignore:

```
bin
include
lib
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would you set up a suitable folder structure for Flask with virtualenv?